# No hacer zoom la hacer .fitBounds() en google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-v3

buen día, hay forma de hacer `mapData.fitBounds(bounds, 0)` sin que haga zoom?, quiero hacer el evento `onZoom()` para no hacer un ciclo infinito. ¿O existe otra manera de acercarse al mapa donde están ubicado los `Marks`?. Es un listado `Marks`, pueden ser 10 o mas, por eso hago el `fitBounds()`.

Esto es lo que hago al hacer `fitBounds()`:

```
const positions = [
  {lat:4.641842, lng: -74.057024},
  {lat:4.6182899553378, lng: -74.067608641125},
  {lat:4.6979978310001, lng: -74.041172752},
  {lat:4.7250384550001, lng: -74.061394685},
  ...
]
const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
positions.forEach(item => {
    const neNew = new window.google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng);

    bounds.extend(neNew);
});

mapData.fitBounds(bounds, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Estableces tú mismo un punto donde hacer zoom por las coordenadas de los Marks.

```
    // Obtener la latitud y longitud de uno de los marcadores
const lat = markers[0].getPosition().lat();
const lng = markers[0].getPosition().lng();

// Establecer la posición central del mapa usando la latitud y longitud del marcador
mapData.setCenter({ lat, lng });

// Establecer el nivel de zoom deseado
mapData.setZoom(8);
```

Comment: hola, buen día gracias por las respuesta, pero son mas 2 posiciones, es un listado de posiciones  que peuden ser 10 o mas osea 10 `marks` por eso hago el `fitBounds(bounds, 0)`